# Spaces being added to start of text box

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, spaces

Ok weird thing I am pulling my hair out with

I have a text box which is being filled by a value from the database (a telephone number)

I have breakpointed the app and checked the value going in to the textbox and the value in the textbox after the assignment and have found it to be correct (07865 345 632)

However when the textbox is shown there appears to be several leading spaces which dont show in the breakpoint info.

Moreover when I then try to assign that value from the text box to a variable it shows and is saved as the original without spaces.

Is there anything that would make this happen without me knowing? does the breakpoint info remove leading spaces in some circumstances?

3 hours on this issue and no progress so any help would be great.

### Summary

1. value recieved from database **BEFORE** assignment to textbox: "07865 345 632"
2. value shown in textbox: "    07865 345 632"
3. value assigned to variable from textbox: "07865 345 632"

Visual Studio 2010 - C# - Windows Forms - SQL Server 2008

HELP! (I only have six hairs and three of them are loose! :-))

Comment: Can you "select" those "leading spaces" in the textbox? Are you sure they're not just (default) padding?

Comment: Yes I can actually delete them

Comment: Do you initialize by any chance the `Text` property before assigning the value from database?

Comment: Could you provide some code how you handle (fill/extract) the textbox?

Comment: What does this output: `Console.Write(textBox1.Text==textBox1.Text.TrimStart())`?

Comment: Is the textbox right aligned?

Comment: No its not, still dont know why this is occuring but I am going to leave it and in true  developer style call it a design feature! :-)

Comment: I would just trim it until you can figure out why the box is behaving this way.  `textBox1.Text = myDbValue.Trim();`

Comment: Please post your textbox code.

Comment: Is the textbox a `MaskedTextBox`? If it is, look at its `Mask` property and check if there are any leading spaces in there.